# How to git add some file to repository?

Tags: git

I want to add some files that `menu.blade.php`, `index.blade.php`, `proses.blade.php` and `show.blade.php`

I try like this :

[image: https://postimg.org/image/g0t9ulmnl/]

```
It's exist error like this : fatal: pathspec ... did not match any file
```

Is there any solution to solve my problem?

Comment: The path is not correct.

Comment: It seems you're asking `git` to add files that does not exist. Can you please explain more about what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

When you *git add x*, git will use *x* as a startingpoint for finding your file. Imagine it as a regex. It therefore takes wildcards such as `*` in order to e.g. add an entire subdirectory at once. (`git add directory/*`)

Your error is pretty clear though. *menu.php* is simply not found. But your *git status* clearly tells you which path you'll have to specify.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I stage files for a commit to avoid typing errors!  It also speeds things up quite a bit.

1. Type `git status` to pull up a list of modified files that you would like to add in the bash window.
2. Type `git add` **press space bar** then **double click or click and drag** on the file that you would like to add so it is highlighted.
3. Next, **press ctrl + insert** this will copy your selection to the clip board.
4. Next, **press shift + insert** this will paste your selection from the clip board to the bash command line.
5. Lastly, **Press Enter** this will now add the file to be staged if everything was typed correctly.

Best Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Note that a simple `git add .` would add all your files.

If it adds too many (like the `table.blade.php`), you can reset it (un-stage it)

```
git reset resources/views/users
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way to add all files in one go in git , you can use this command after

```
git init
```

then use `git add --a`